# React Native Error "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting the following error in React Native and have looked at multiple posts of people with the same issue and I'm still not having any luck solving this. Not sure what is causing this issue exactly.

HERE IS MY APP.JS CODE

```js
import * as Expo from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, AppRegistry, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
import HostClient from './app/Views/HostClientView';
import ClientQueue from './app/Views/ClientQueue';
import SearchBarr from './app/components/Searchbar';


export default class App extends React.Component {
   static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Welcome',
   };

render() {
   return (
     <Image style = {styles.container} source={require('./app/images/jukebox-background.jpg')} resizeMode="cover">
        <View>
           <HostClient />
       </View>
     </Image>
   );
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
   HostClientView: { screen: HostClient },
   ClientQueueView: { screen: ClientQueue},
});
```

HERE IS MY HOSTCLIENT.JS WHICH I MADE THE MAIN VIEW WITH ALL COMPONENTS

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, AppRegistry, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, 
FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Host from '../../components/Host/Host.js';
import UserRequest from '../../components/UserRequest/UserRequest.js';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Button from 'react-native-button';



export default class HostClient extends React.Component {

   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Host />
            <UserRequest />
            <Button style = {styles.button} title="ClientQueueView"
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ClientQueueView') }> <Image style = {styles.turntable} source={require('../../images/vinyl2.png')} resizeMode="contain"/>
            </Button>
         </View>
      );
   }
}
```

AND FINALLY HERE IS THE USER.JS FILE

```
// Request Component
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, AppRegistry, Text, View, Image } from 'react-
native';
import Button from 'react-native-button';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


export default class UserRequest extends Component {

static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
const {state, navigate} = navigation;
return {
  title: 'Noah Testing'
};
};

constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  address: [],
  refreshing: false,
  page: 1,
  lastPage: 1,
  loading: true,
  listOpacity: 0,
};
}



render() {
return (
  <View >
  <Text > Request </Text>
  <Button  title="ClientQueueView"
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ClientQueueView') }> <Image style = {styles.turntable} source={require('../../images/vinyl2.png')} resizeMode="contain"/>
    </Button>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Comment: So which line is causing the error exactly ?

Comment: Figured it out. Lot's of errors in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
APP.JS   
import * as Expo from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, AppRegistry, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, 
FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


import HostClient from './app/Views/HostClientView';
import ClientQueue from './app/Views/ClientQueue';
import SearchBarr from './app/components/Searchbar';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
HostClientView: { screen: HostClient },
ClientQueueView: { screen: ClientQueue}
});

 export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor (){
    super();
  }
  static navigationOptions = {
title: 'Welcome',
};

render() {
return (
  <Image style = {styles.container} source=
{require('./app/images/jukebox-background.jpg')} resizeMode="cover">
    <View>
    <AppNavigator ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }} />
    </View>
  </Image>
);
}
}

HOSTCLIENT.JS

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, AppRegistry, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, 
FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';
import Host from '../../components/Host/Host.js';
import UserRequest from '../../components/UserRequest/UserRequest.js';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import ClientQueue from '../ClientQueue';




export default class HostClient extends React.Component {

constructor(){
super();
 }

someEvent() {
// call navigate for AppNavigator here:
this.navigator && this.navigator.dispatch({ type: 'Navigate', 
routeName, params });
}

render() {

return (

    <View>
      <Host />
      <UserRequest nav={this.props.navigation}/>
    </View>
);
}
}
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
ClientQueueView: { screen: ClientQueue}
});

USERREQUEST.JS
// Request Component

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, AppRegistry, Text, View, Image } from 'react-
native';
import Button from 'react-native-button';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import ClientQueue from '../../Views/ClientQueue';


export default class UserRequest extends Component {
constructor(){
super();
}

someEvent() {
// call navigate for AppNavigator here:
this.navigator && this.navigator.dispatch({ type: 'Navigate', 
routeName, params });
}

render() {
return (
    <View style = {styles.view}>
  <Text style = {styles.request}> Request </Text>
  <Button style = {styles.button} onPress={() => 
this.props.nav.navigate('ClientQueueView')}> <Image style = 
{styles.turntable} source={require('../../images/vinyl2.png')} 
resizeMode="contain"/>
    </Button>
    </View>
);
}
}

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
ClientQueueView: { screen: ClientQueue}
});
```